# How to optimize this multiple sums?

Tags: summation, convergence

I need to perform this sum

$$
\sum_{n_1=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n_2=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n_3=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n_4=1}^{\infty} \frac{K_{1} \left(\frac{a}{x} \sqrt{n_1^2 + 4 y_2^2 x^2 n_2^2 + 4 y_3^2 x^2 n_3^2 + 4 y_4^2 x^2 n_4^2} \right)}{\sqrt{n_1^2 + 4 y_2^2 x^2 n_2^2 + 4 y_3^2 x^2 n_3^2 + 4 y_4^2 x^2 n_4^2}}
$$
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind.

I think this sum converges more easily whether $x y_i > 1/2$, but when $x y_i < 1/2$ this job seems to be hard. I try to implement a primitive code to make this sum for a finite sum (instead of an infinity sum, I do a finite sum with a number that respects a certain approximation)

```
fun[x_, y2_, y3_, y4_, k_] := Sum[BesselK[1,1/x Sqrt[n1^2 + 4 x^2 y2^2 n2^2 + 4 x^2 y3^2 n3^2  +4 x^2 y4^2 n4^2 ]]/Sqrt[n1^2 + 4 x^2 y2^2 n2^2 + 4 x^2 y3^2 n3^2  + 4 x^2 y4^2 n4^2], {n1,1,k}, {n2, 1,k-n1}, {n3,1,k-n1-n2}, {n4, 1, k-n3-n2-n1}]

ki = 15;
i = 1;
While[fun[1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ki]/fun[1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ki + 5] <= 0.999, 
      {ki = ki + 5, Print[ki, ",", fun[1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, ki]]};
      imax = i;
      i++;];
```

this primitive code just is useful for giving me the $k$ number of parcels. There is a relation between $k$ and the argument of the Bessel function.

However when $x y_i \ll 1$ (e.g. $y_i = 0.01$ in the above code) the number of parcels grows very rapidly and the sum is hard to converge. I think making for Abel-plana and NSum isn't possible. Please, can someone help me to perform this sum in a smarter way than me?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Mathematica code for the sum

Comment: Those radicals look identical. Are they?

Comment: @BobHanlon I made an edit

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, the radical is the same inside the Bessel function.